# animate custom property generates error 'can not be animated'

Tags: animation

I am setting values (and keyframing) for custom properties of my animation from a python script. For most of the custom properties I make this works fine, however there are also custom properties that generate the error 'bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "["Clamp High"]" not animatable'. In the IU the properties show like in the image: [image]

when I press the the 'I' key in the UI I get the same error. However, when I press edit of the particular custom property and immediately press OK, it shows like
[image]

and I can press 'I' and insert a keyframe.

What is happening here?

Comment: I found the issue: I was setting string type values which cause the issue. Pressing edit and OK in Blender most probably converts it to float and make it work. Explicitely converting all values to float in my python sccript solves the issue